# Invitation to connect with linkedin api

Tags: ruby, api, linkedin-api

I wonder how can I send invitation to connect via `linkedin-oauth2` gem?
I don't mean sending email or inmail, but simple invitation to connect, like friendship in facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just patched a version of the linkedin gem to include the connect_by_email(email) method. https://github.com/brianpetro/linkedin

For example:

```
client.connect_by_email("you@example.com")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I applied this to an oauth2 fork in case anyone needs it.

https://github.com/benbruscella/linkedin-oauth2